# Where is the best information about the contents of bitcoind 0.8.2?

Tags: bitcoind, protocol

[There seem to be a few interesting changes in this version](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/1drslh/082_will_not_eliminate_microtransactions/), possibly affecting the protocol itself (de facto).

Where can I find the most relevant, concise yet detailed information about this version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 0.8.2 makes **no changes to the protocol**, to make that sure.

The official information on the change that everyone is talking about is [**this pull request**](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/2577) on GitHub.

You can find some people trying to make conclusions about the effects of the change on BitcoinTalk and Reddit. Keep in mind that they are not official representatives of the developer team and that they often proclaim incorrect information.

The only correct statement is the one in the pull request. Probably there will be some release notes as well as soon as the update gets pushed.